# How can I disable the CSRF filter on Play 2.6?

Tags: scala, csrf, postman, playframework-2.6

I've been trying to use Postman with my Play Framework API, but I keep running into problems related to the CSRF Filter.

I've browsed a few forums (including SO) looking for a fix to this, and the proverbial advice seems to be adding:

```
play.filters.disabled+=play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter
```

to the `application.conf` file.

I've tried performing that fix, but even when I do so, I continue to get this error in the console logs:

```
[warn] p.filters.CSRF - [CSRF] Check failed because no token found in headers for /auth/logout
```

Where `/auth/logout` is a POST request with the `Authorization` cookie set as a JWT.

I've tried a number of alternative fixes, such as setting `play.filters.disabled` to `[]` or `null`, allowing all hosts through the CORS filter, various combinations of all 3, etc, but ultimately the same error appears in my logs.

The only thing that's made a change to the application at all is setting the CSRF token as a cookie instead of in the session, which changes the error to:

```
[warn] p.filters.CSRF - [CSRF] Check failed because none/none for /auth/logout
```

This gives me the comfort of knowing at least that the `application.conf` is being loaded correctly, but it still doesn't fix the problem.

Is there a correct way to disable the CSRF filter that I'm not doing properly? Is there another way to allow Postman to work through the CSRF filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I figured out the issue, but it was a bit tricky to dig up the source of the issue.

When I had added macwire to the project for dependency injection, I had to define a custom application loader, which needed a custom `AppComponents` class. My declaration for the `AppComponents` class looked something like this:

`class AppComponents(context: Context) 
    extends BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context)
    with MyModule
    with AssetsComponents
    with I18nComponents
    with play.filters.HttpFiltersComponents`

As is now apparent, `play.filters.HttpFiltersComponents` has the following field:

`def httpFilters: Seq[EssentialFilter] = Seq(csrfFilter, securityHeadersFilter, allowedHostsFilter)`

Where `csrfFilter`, `securityHeadersFilter`, and `allowedHostsFilter` are effectively hard-coded values. I guess when using a custom `ApplicationLoader`, it ignores the http filters set in the `application.conf` file (which seems obvious as I write this).

<strike>A current workaround/fix that I'm using is to set `val httpFilters: Seq[EssentialFilter] = Seq(securityHeadersFilter, allowedHostsFilter)`, instead of the default `HttpFiltersComponents` field. I'll probably modify this a bit to read the filters in from the configuration file, but for now this gets around the problem.</strike>

**TL;DR:** Added a custom ApplicationLoader when integrating MacWire, didn't realize this would shadow the fields in the config file.

### EDIT

The final code in my `ApplicationLoader` for configuring the HTTP filters with macwire looks as follows, in case anyone else needs it. It uses almost the exact same code as `HttpFiltersComponents`, but with macwire instead of Guice (undefined variables are inherited from `BuiltInComponentsFromContext`):

```
override lazy val httpFilters: Seq[EssentialFilter] = {
    val wiredInstance: Wired = wiredInModule(this)
    val classes: Seq[Class[EssentialFilter]] = {
        val disabledFilters = config.get[Seq[String]]("play.filters.disabled")
        val enabledFilters = config.get[Seq[String]]("play.filters.enabled").filterNot(disabledFilters.contains)
        try {
            for (filterClassName <- enabledFilters) yield {
                try {
                    environment.classLoader.loadClass(filterClassName).asInstanceOf[Class[EssentialFilter]]
                } catch {
                    case e: ClassNotFoundException =>
                      throw configuration.reportError("play.filters.enabled", s"Cannot load class $filterClassName", Some(e))
                }
            }
        } catch {
            case e: ConfigException.Null =>
                Nil
            case e: ConfigException.Missing =>
                Nil
        }
    }
    classes.map(x => wiredInstance.wireClassInstance(x))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add in your application.conf this code:

```
play.filters.hosts {
  allowed = ["."]
}
```

let me know in it's works for you.
Check also official play [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Migration26#CSRFFilter).

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately that still gives `[warn] p.filters.CSRF - [CSRF] Check failed because no token found in headers for /auth/logout`, with or without `play.filters.disabled` set

Comment: `play.filters.disabled+=play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter` also in application.conf?

Comment: Found the source of the issue: when I added MacWire, I had added a custom `ApplicationLoader` class without realizing at the time that this would hard code filters, ignoring the config file.